# While в питон игнорирует условие

Tags: python

Как оформить while таким образом, чтобы он заканчивал работу при определенном количестве безуспешных попыток трай, но при этом мог закончить раньше, если другая переменная будет условию соответствовать? Сейчас kk=1, но цикл не прекращается

```
def proverka():
    kk = 0
    i = 0
    print("\nIP....")
    global InfoIP
    global InfoIP2
    try:
        driver.execute_script('window.open("https://2ip.ru/")')
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        while (kk != 1) or (i != 10):
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                InfoIP[0] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d_clip_button"]/span').text
                InfoIP2[0] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d_clip_button"]/span').text
            except Exception:
                i += 1
            else:
                kk = 1
                print("kk")
        if i == 10:
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            work()
```

Comment: В `while (kk != 1) or (i != 10):` вместо `or` наверное `and` предполагалось поставить. Также можно выйти из цикла с помощью `break`

Comment: Действительно, переменная `kk` тут вообще не нужна, ведь после успешной попытки цикл элементарно прерывается с помощью break

Comment: Про break не знал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вам вместо кода в блоке `else:` использовать `break`, результат в вашем случае будет таким же. Полный код:

```
def proverka():
    kk = 0
    i = 0
    print("\nIP....")
    global InfoIP
    global InfoIP2
    try:
        driver.execute_script('window.open("https://2ip.ru/")')
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        while (kk != 1) or (i != 10):
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                InfoIP[0] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d_clip_button"]/span').text
                InfoIP2[0] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d_clip_button"]/span').text
            except Exception:
                i += 1
            else:
                break
        if i == 10:
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            work()
```